# Histogram with two variable in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, histogram

I have a data set like this :

```
ID  z  N
0   0.15    69.0
1   0.25    208.0
2   0.35    402.0
3   0.45    223.0
4   0.55    327.0
5   0.65    136.0
6   0.75    136.0
7   0.85    136.0
8   0.95    136.0
9   1.05    136.0
10  1.15    136.0
11  1.25    136.0
12  1.35    136.0
13  1.45    136.0
14  1.55    136.0
15  1.65    136.0
```

I would like to make a plot this
[image]

I cannot find the way out. A simple `plt.hist()` is a single function plot. Or a `plt.bar(z,N)` wont dissolve the lines between bars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `plt.hist` is expecting a list of values from which it will calculate the frequencies. Since you already have the frequencies, you could remake the list of values and let `plt.hist` work the way it was made to

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

z = [0.15, 0.25, 0.35, 0.45, 0.55, 0.65, 0.75, 0.85, 0.95, 1.05, 1.15, 1.25, 1.35, 1.45, 1.55, 1.65]
N = [69.0, 208.0, 402.0, 223.0, 327.0, 136.0, 136.0, 136.0, 136.0, 136.0, 136.0, 136.0, 136.0, 136.0, 136.0, 136.0]
hist_vals = []
for n,zz in zip(N,z):
    hist_vals += [zz]*int(n)
plt.hist(hist_vals,bins=z+[1.7], histtype='step', edgecolor='k')
plt.show()
```

[image: Histogram]